# HttpURLConnection doing a get request even after setDoOutput(true), setRequestMethod("POST") setRequestProperty("Content

Tags: java, android, post, http-post, httpurlconnection

Here is the code:

```
String Surl = "http://mysite.com/somefile";
String charset = "UTF-8";
query = String.format("param1=%s&param2=%s",
URLEncoder.encode("param1", charset),
URLEncoder.encode("param2", charset));

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(Surl + "?" + query).openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");             
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","<em>Android</em>");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);                
urlConnection.connect();
```

The above still does a `GET` request. I am using PHP on the server and am able to access the query's 'name=value' params through the `$_GET` variable and not the `$_POST` variable
Tested on 2.3.7(device).

What am I missing ?

Comment: This looks a bit suspect: Surl + "?" + query.  How are you validating it's doing a get request?

Comment: @tjg184 I am using PHP on the server and am able to access the query's 'name=value' params through the `$_GET` variable and not the `$_POST` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send parameters in the url they are put in the GET variable. You should be posting the parameters in the POST body of the request to achieve what you are looking for. You should add the following just before the connect() call and remove the "?" + query from the url.

```
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(query.getBytes().length));            
    urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(query.getBytes().length);

    OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());            
    output.write(query.getBytes());
    output.flush(); 
    output.close();
```

Comment: Did not know the parameters had to be written manually when doing a post! That resolved it. Thanks.